# Calling data from server in ionic app

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

[image: Service Code]

In my Ionic app I am able to serve my data from .factory but I would like to get my data from server (JSON), I have tried a lot of codes already but was not able to solve the problem. Please suggest me a code to write here at services.js file so that I could get my data from http://localhost:3000/statments.

Have a look at above Service code to see how I am fetching my data from services.js

Answer (score 0):

```
//controller  
 app.controller('YourControllerName', YourControllerName);
 function YourControllerName($scope, myService) {
    $scope.fetchData = function() {
       myService.getData().then(function(result) {
         console.log(result.data);
       });
    }
 };

 //service.js
 app.service("myService", function ($http) {
     this.getData = function() {
        return $http.get('http://localhost:3000/');
     }
 });
```